# How to authenticate an user using ADFS in xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin

I am new to xamarin forms. I need to authenticate the users using ADFS. Please guide me what are all the information required and what are the processing steps?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should replace (server url: "https://<your_fsname>/adfs") `your_fsname` from `adfs.contoso.com` with like this `localhost:44320/`.Then client can connect to the local server.And they must be on the same network segment.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs

Answer (score -1):

You can use following link for setup Azure Active Directory Application on Azure and integrating in your Xamarin.Form mobile App.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-login-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I am expecting for local server ADFS (Not cloud).

Comment: if you use a local server then your app will only work when it's connected to that server's local network